como subo un archivo nuevo a mi github?
Hice un archivo nuevo y no quiero que afecte al ultimo que subí, soy nueva en esto.
Tengo otra carpeta con unos archivos que no quiero modificar pero no encuentro el lugar donde subir un proyecto diferente.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! si queres subirlo en otro proyecto, entonces tenes que hacer otro proyecto, no el mismo.. es confusa tu pregunta...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
